# Could we see a vote breakdown on tag synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, vote-count

How about letting us see a vote breakdown on tag synonyms, just like on normal question and answer votes (and triggered the same way)?

Comment: +1 I would be interested in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This seems like a very interesting idea.